# Como resolver os TypeError de funções indefinidas de jQuery.nicescroll e UniteGallery aborrecidos nos ficheiros PHP? É por causa da versão de jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

- Bootstrap 4.0.0 Beta usa jQuery 3.2.1
- UniteGallery usa jQuery 11.0
- jQuery.nicescroll usa jQuery 2

Uso PHP

Uso só o jQuery 3. Não quero ter várias versões de jQuery. Veja a ordem de ficheiros Javascript. Não vi nenhum erro nesses códigos:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/unitegallery.js'></script>   
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/ug-theme-tiles.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("html").niceScroll({
    cursorwidth: 12,
    cursoropacitymin: 0.5,
    cursorcolor: '#ff8a80',
    cursorborder: 'none',
    cursorborderradius: 10,
    autohidemode: 'leave',
    horizrailenabled:false
  }); 

  $("#mc-scroll").niceScroll({
    cursorborderradius: 3, 
    cursorcolor:"#1a237e", 
    cursoropacitymin: 0, 
    cursorwidth: "3px", 
    railpadding: { top: 0, left: 0 }
  });

  $("#fotogaleria").unitegallery();

});
</script>
```

No ficheiro `index.php` e não há nenhum erro nele.

```
<body>

  <?php include("cabecalho.php") ?>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">          
          <?php include("fotogaleria.php") ?>          
        </div>
      </div> <!-- row -->
    </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
  </div> <!-- wrapper -->  

  <?php include("rodape.php") ?>

</body>
</html>
```

No ficheiro `fotogaleria.php` que é incluído dentro do `indexa.php`:

```
<div id="fotogaleria" style="display:none;">
   <a href="imagens/noivos/noivos1.jpg">
     <img alt="<?php echo _alt_novios1 ?>"
     src="imagens/noivos/noivos1.jpg"
     data-image="imagens/noivos/noivos1.jpg"
     data-description="<?php echo _alt_novios1 ?>"
     style="display:none">
   </a>           
</div>
```

Eis os erros:

- No caso de jQuery.nicescroll, mas os códigos de função em Javascript estão correctos:

`TypeError: self.autohidedom.stop is not a function. (In 'self.autohidedom.stop()', 'self.autohidedom.stop' is undefined)`

- No caso de UniteGallery:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.easing["swing"]')`

O erro mostrou a linha do código de UniteGallery:

```
(function(factory) { if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) { define(["jquery"], function($) { return factory($) }) } else if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") { exports = factory(require("jquery")) } else { factory(jQuery) } })(function($) { $.easing["jswing"] = $.easing["swing"]; var pow = Math.pow,
```

- No caso de jQuery causado pelo UniteGallery:

`TypeError: $("#fotogaleria").unitegallery is not a function. (In '$("#fotogaleria").unitegallery()', '$("#fotogaleria").unitegallery' is undefined)`

E a linha de jQuery:

```
jQuery.readyException = function(error) {
​    window.setTimeout(function() {
​        throw error;
​    });
};
```

Comment: Como estão as ordens de chamada aos arquivos `JS`? a primeira linha chama os `JQuery` e as bibliotecas na sequencia? ou estão misturados? na documentação do `UniteGallery usa jQuery 11.0` e 
`jQuery.nicescroll usa jQuery 2` não tem dependências de outras versões do `JQuery`, pelo erro apresentado os dados estão indefinidos, pode ser as dependências que você já mencionou na pergunta.

Comment: As ordens estão correctas, jQuery tem de ficar no primeiro lugar para que outras bibliotecas funcionem na sequência e por ordem. Já mudei de ordem das bibliotecas e os erros ainda são mesmos. Sim, eles utilizam, mas achei estranho, porque num outro projecto, com jQuery 3.2.1. e jQuery.nicescrol, o nicescroll apareceu normalmente sem nenhum erro. Talvez por causa de dependências de jQuery ou PHP?

Comment: Teste o UniteGallery noutro mesmo projecto e ele apareceu normalmente, junto com o nicescroll. Acho que é por causa de PHP.